# android webview make the page header div not move, but the content div below it scrollable

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

I am currently doing an android webview app. I want to make the header div on the top not move, but the content div below it scrollable. Any one have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching online, I got the answer data-position="fixed".